# Prism with Xamarin.Forms - how to autowire ContentView which is inside another ContentView

Tags: xamarin.forms, prism

We are successfully wiring ContentViews to their ViewModels when the ContentView is directly contained in a Page, using XAML like:

```
<local:AwesomeView mvvm:ViewModelLocator.AutowirePartialView=”{x:Reference self}” />
```

Where *self* is the parent page.

However, we have ContentViews which contain ContentViews, and using *AutoWirePartialView* as above for the nested view does not work. The ContentViews don't get wired up to their ViewModels.

Looking at the Prism code:

1. AutoWirePartialView has the comment *"This API is Obsolete and will
   be removed during the 8.0 previews"*
2. The property changed handler for AutoWirePartialView explicitly checks for the parent being a *Page*, so won't work with a parent ContentView

So it's fairly clear from the Prism code why this won't work!

Is there a way to achieve this with Prism?

**Versions:**
Xamarin.Forms - 4.4.0.991265

Prism - 7.1.0.431

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My opinion, in order to keep things clean, is to use the default prism approach and bind a viewmodel to the respective page only and not to any subviews.

Any binding to a component inside the page should be made through properties on the page's viewmodel so you can achieve bindings no matter the depth of the content view in the display hierarchy.

For instance:

Your page's view model

```
public class PageAViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
   public ContentViewAViewModel ContentViewViewModel
   {
      get { return _contentViewViewModel; }
      set { SetProperty(ref _contentViewViewModel, value); }
   }
}
```

Your page's view

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<views:BasePage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                xmlns:components="clr-YourProject.Components"
                xmlns:views="clr-YourProject.Views"
                x:Class="YourProject.Views.PageA">
     <Grid RowSpacing="0">
          <Grid RowSpacing="0">
                <components:ContentViewA BindingContext="{Binding ContentViewViewModel}"/>
          </Grid>
    </Grid>
</views:BasePage>
```

Comment: Thanks - I think this is the easiest way to achieve what I want at the moment. It gets round the 'problem' while we wait for Prism 8.

Comment: Glad to have helped with this workaround. I'm sure Dan's update on Prism will provide you with a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 2):

Partial Views are indeed being made Obsolete. The reason it's obsolete is that we are bringing [Region support](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/pull/2077) to Prism 8. Partial Views were always meant as a quick and temporary solution to help bridge the gap until we got to implementing Regions for Prism.Forms. Regions are far more powerful and will let you do a lot more like nesting, and lazily loading views.

Realistically the concept of nested Regions where you have:

> ComponentViewA which has its own ViewModel.
>
> Then you have ComponentViewB which has it's own ViewModel and has ComponentViewA as a child
>
> And ComponentViewA is itself a child of AwesomePage

It sounds like this is the general concept that you're looking to support. So the short answer is that in Prism 7 there is no good way of doing this. There are certainly some hacks like you could for instance pass the page as a parameter and set the property in the code behind like:

```cs
public class ComponentViewB : ContentView
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty ParentPageProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(nameof(ParentPage), typeof(Page), typeof(ComponentViewB), null, propertyChanged: OnParentPageChanged);

    private static void OnParentPageChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        // This guards the action from being performed more than once.
        if(oldValue is null && newValue != null && bindable is ComponentViewB view)
        {
            // This assumes you've set the property x:Name="componentViewA"
            // for your ComponentViewA in XAML
            ViewModelLocator.SetAutowirePartialView(view.componentViewA, (view.ParentPage);
        }
    }

    public Page ParentPage
    {
        get => (Page)GetValue(ParentPageProperty);
        set => SetValue(ParentPageProperty, value);
    }
}
```

To be honest if I had to make something work today this is how I would recommend doing it. Once we merge the PR I referenced above I would suggest that you update to the previews and migrate to use Regions.

Comment: Thanks - that's an interesting solution. I think xerx's solution above is a bit tighter - as with your solution we'd have to add knowledge of the parent view to each ContentView.